# react-native-router-flux, keep state when reloading

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a scene structure based on tabs:

**Current code structure**

*Routes.js*

```
class Routes extends Component {

  render() {

    function selector(props) {
      return props.auth.isLoggedIn ? (props.auth.isVerified? 'home': 'authenticate') : 'authenticate'
    }

    const component = connect(state => ({
      auth: state.auth,
    }))(Switch)

    return (
      <AppRouter>
        <Scene key="root" component={component} tabs selector={selector} hideNavBar hideTabBar>
          <Scene key="authenticate" hideTabBar>
            <Scene type="replace" key="login" initial component={GradientBackground(LoginScreen)} hideNavBar/>
            <Scene type="replace" key="register" component={GradientBackground(RegisterScreen)} hideNavBar/>
            <Scene type="replace" key="forgotPassword" component={GradientBackground(ForgotPasswordScreen)} hideNavBar/>
            <Scene type="replace" key="emailConfirmation" component={GradientBackground(EmailConfirmationScreen)} hideNavBar/>
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="home" component={NavigationDrawer} type="replace">
            {require('./scenes/home')}
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </AppRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

*home.js*

```
module.exports = (
  <Scene key="isLoggedIn" unmountScenes initial>
    {require('./dashboard.js')}
    {require('./profile.js')}
    {require('./challenges.js')}
    {require('./friends.js')}
  </Scene>
)
```

*Dashboard.js*

```
module.exports = (
  <Scene type="replace" key="dashboard" initial navigationBarStyle={styles.transparent} drawerImage={Images.menu} renderRightButton={() => <RoundedButton text="dashboard"/>}>
    <Scene key="dashboard_home" component={GradientBackground(DashboardScreen)}/>
  </Scene>
)
```

*Friends.js*

```
module.exports = (
  <Scene key="friends" initial navigationBarStyle={styles.transparent} drawerImage={Images.menu} renderRightButton={() => <RoundedButton text="dashboard"/>}>
    <Scene key="inviteFriends" component={GradientBackground(FriendsInviteScreen)} hideNavBar/>
  </Scene>
)
```

when navigating through the app everything works fine.

**Actual behaviour**

When I hit reload (or Cmd+R), the current shown scene, ex. a profile screen, get's reset to another completely different scene.

Ex. currently the logic in my app goes like this:

first time user logs in -> show friend invitation screen -> go to dashboard page
every other log in -> go to dashboard page

however whenever I hit Cmd+R I always get sent to friend invitation screen, needless to say, this is very annoying and time consuming.

Comment: You have written initial in dashboard and friend also so react native router flux considers last one friend as initial scene.

Comment: this is not the right way to determine initial scene

Comment: only one screen will be initial you have to navigate through some boolean flag to another

Comment: alright, thanks for pointing that out, still, this does not solve my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling with the code and reading more of the documentation, it appears there is no simple way to do this (not even sure it is possible), it seems this would be a new feature for the library.

I'm now using `hot reloading` (shake gesture -> enable hot reloading), it is not ideal, there some cases where the behavior is not as expected and I have to reload the browser and manually navigate to the page, but for 70-80% of the time this achieves what I wanted.